# TextArea Issue - Text within Angle Brackets Disappears while Typing

Tags: javascript, extjs, textarea

When a user enters text that includes angle brackets, the text and the brackets disappear after the closing bracket key is entered into the `TextArea` on the dialog.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var some_textarea = new Ext.form.TextArea({
    id: 'some_textarea',
    name: 'name',
    hiddenName: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Field Label',
    width: 486,
    height: 150,
    autoScroll: true,
    labelSeparator: Common.required_asterisk,
    allowBlank: false,
    blankText: 'Data is required',
    emptyClass: 'required-textfield',
    emptyText: ' ',
    msgTarget: 'under'
});
```

Any idea on how to allow the entry of angle brackets (in a WYSIWYG fashion) is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is this "ext" thing, is it a library's class?

Comment: You're using ExtJS right? It's probably a "feature" intended to prevent XSS attacks. There's probably a way to disable it but Ext documentation does not appear to be public. *edit* oh I guess it is :)

Comment: There appears to be [pretty extensive documentation on this widget](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html)...

Comment: It sounds like you need to HTML-escape output in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yes, this is ExtJS.

Comment: I have looked in the Ext.form.field.TextArea documentation of this for ExtJS, but have not found a way to disable the rendering to html.

Comment: I have never seen such a problem during my work with ExtJS 4.2.1 and 6.2.1. Which version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: We are using ExtJS 3.2.1

Comment: I don't believe we can upgrade to 4.2.1 easily. Is there a way to address this without upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a very old version of ExtJs (version 3.2.1). Feedback I am getting seems to indicate that people using versions greater than 4.2.1 are not experiencing this issue, so I will consider the need to migrate to at least 4.2.1 as the only solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would strongly recommend you to upgrade to higher version, but as an alternative solution

how about, one keypress, check the angle bracket and convert it with [<] or some other text. and before saving it replace [].

Answer (score 0):

here you can override the setValue function of TextArea and `Ext.util.Format. htmlEncode` something like this.

```
setValue : function(v){
    if(this.emptyText && this.el && !Ext.isEmpty(v)){
        this.el.removeClass(this.emptyClass);
    }

    v = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(v);

    Ext.form.TextField.superclass.setValue.apply(this, arguments);
    this.applyEmptyText();
    this.autoSize();
    return this;
},
```

Comment: thank you for this. However, I am not sure I understand where to put this code as it relates to my original code snippet. Grateful any clarification.

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy I am quite a surprise, i am also working in Extjs 3.4 but i never face this kind of issue. is it possible for you to create extjs fiddle by demonstrating the issue. i had tried but still not able to reproduce it  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2i9o